# Error calling updateUserAttributes in AWS Amplify

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

When calling the updateUserAttributes in Amplify I get the following errors:

```
2019-03-13 08:31:18.937 25019-25057 E/ReactNativeJS: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Object.keys(styles)[typeof Symbol === "function" ? Symbol.iterator : "@@iterator"]()')
2019-03-13 08:31:18.942 25019-25057 E/ReactNativeJS: undefined is not a function (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[2], "pretty-format")(error)')
```

The calling code looks like this:

```
const user = await getCurrentAuthenticatedUser();
Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, { 'custom:token': token } ).then(result =>{ console.log(result)});
```

getCurrentAuthenticatedUser wraps the Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser function and returns the user from Cognito.

Amplify version: 1.1.22

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved.

Adding a .catch to the function call resolves the bug:

```
Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, { 'custom:token': token } )
    .then(result =>{ console.log(result)})
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```